# Compile not correctly initializing a variable defined inside Module

Tags: bugs, compile, scoping

**Bug introduced in 8.0, fixed in 10.4, intentionally reintroduced in 11.0 and persisting through 13.0.0 or later**

---

In the following example, inside the `minimumX`'s `Module`, `x` is initialized to 1, but the results say otherwise:

```
solutionQ = Function[{x, d}, IntegerQ[Sqrt[(x^2 - 1)/d]] && x != 1];
minimumX = 
  Compile[{{d, _Integer}}, 
   Module[{x = 1}, While[! solutionQ[x, d], x++]; x]];

minimumX[2]
minimumX[3]
minimumX[2]

(*
3

7

17
*)
```

If I define `minimumX` as:

```
minimumX = 
  Function[{d}, Module[{x = 1}, While[! solutionQ[x, d], x++]; x]];
```

or

```
minimumX = 
  Compile[{{d, _Integer}}, 
   Module[{x = 1}, x = 1; While[! solutionQ[x, d], x++]; x]];
```

It works as I was expecting:

```
(*
3

2

3
*)
```

Is this expected behavior, or should I report a bug?

(Mathematica 9.0.1)

Comment: This is definitely not expected and you should report it. The localization of `x` in the instruction `{46, Function[{d}, While[ !solutionQ[x, d], x++]], {x, 2, 0, 1, Module}, 2, 0, 0, 6, 0, 17}` is clearly not being respected. The same behavior is observed for `With` in place of `Module`, but not for `Block`, which works as it should. It also works correctly in versions 7 and 5.2; the bug seems to have been introduced in version 8, when major changes were made to the VM. (The compiled code generated by all versions is functionally identical and differs only by opcode numbering.)

Comment: For completeness, let me just note that the function can be written more optimally as `With[{solutionQ = Function[{x, d}, FractionalPart[Sqrt[(x^2 - 1)/d]] == 0 && x != 1]}, minimumX = Compile[{{d, _Integer}}, Module[{x = 1}, While[! solutionQ[x, d], x++]; x]]]`. This is somewhat beside the point as far as the question goes since the bug does not manifest in this case, but I'm sure others would have been moved to comment on it if I hadn't. Indeed, I think it's worth emphasizing to WRI support that this particular non-optimal formulation is necessary to expose the bug.

Comment: I think, what's worth noticing is:
if You define minimumX by `SetDelayed(:=)` not only `Set(=)` it works like it should.

Comment: Thank you all. I've just reported the bug.

Comment: I know it has been a long time, but this bug is still there in 10.0.2. One thing I tried though, if you initialize `x` in the `Module` by a delayed assignment, that is `Module[{x:=1},..` it works, but the resulting numbers are actually floating numbers `(* 3.  2.  3. *)` ... I see contradicting logic here.

Comment: This was fixed in version 10.4 and intentionally rebroken to address a [huge slowdown](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110285/has-compilation-of-big-programs-become-excessively-sluggish-in-v-10-4).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau but it will eventually have a bright future, right? Just coming with the new compiler technology?

Comment: @P.Fonseca (late reply, I know) I can only say that I hope so.