# Mathematica8 can compile this function but Mathematica 9 can't if I set CompilationTarget -> "C"

Tags: bugs, compile

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and persisting through 11.0**

---

Following code worked on Mathematica 8, but in Mathematica 9 it can't be compiled, it return this message

> CompiledFunction::cflist: Nontensor object generated; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>

How can I fix this?

```
Clear[cf1];
cf1 = Compile[{},
   Module[{s = 0.0},
    Do[
      If[s > 15, Print@i; Break[]];
      s = s + 1.0/i;
      , {i, 10^7}];
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C"];

cf1[]
```

Comment: You function does not return anything and it uses a `Print` which is never a good idea inside a compiled function. Removing the `Print` fixed your problem here.

Comment: Although I haven't tried it, I'm certain that @halirutan is correct so, probably, V9 is doing a *better* job of flagging uncompilable functions In addition, I'd point out that I don't see any output coming from your function. Perhaps, you should replace `Do` with `Table` and remove the semi-colon from the final statement inside the loop.

Comment: Regardless of the fact that the use of `Print` is not optimal, this does seem to be a bug in the version 9 VM or `CCodeGenerator\`` package. The same bytecode is generated by versions 8 and 9, but the interpretation of it by version 9 seems to be incorrect. It's not clear to me why this only shows up with `CompilationTarget -> "C"`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. But `Print`, so far as I know, is not compilable.  It certainly doesn't appear in the list ``Compile`CompilerFunctions[]`` and `CompilePrint[cf1]` reveals a callback to `MainEvaluate`.

Comment: @MarkMcClure that's correct, but irrelevant to the situation except in as much as it might expose a bug that would remain hidden otherwise (cf. [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25075)). The presence of a call back into the interpreter certainly should not trigger an exception that leads to re-evaluation of the entire function, and especially not in a version-specific way and only for a particular compilation target. I think the most likely situation is that version 9 produces an incorrect translation of the bytecode to C.

Comment: @OleksandrR. do you know if this bug is fixed in v10?

Comment: This issue still persists. Is it reported and confirmed by WRI to be a bug than intended design?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In version 8, the callback into the interpreter (also known as `MainEvaluate` or `WolframCompileLibrary_Functions->evaluateFunctionExpression`) looks like

```
Function[{iCompile$1}, Block[{i = iCompile$1}, {Print[i], i}]][register]
```

where `register` is the (integer, scalar) register that contains the value of `i`. This looks correct to me, although I'll admit that I don't understand the reason for translating `Print[i]` into `{Print[i], i}`.

In version 9, however, it takes the incorrect form:

```
Function[{}, Print[i]][register]
```

Since this is obviously wrong (which one can also see from the fact that `i` is printed literally), the question might as well ask why it works at all, even without translating the bytecode to C. The reason is that the *bytecode* contains the instruction

```
{46, Function[{}, Print[i]], {i, 2, 0, 3, Block}, 6, 0, 17}
```

in both versions, and it is the responsibility of the execution host (either the VM, or the `` CCodeGenerator` `` package in case of translation to C) to interpret this into a valid call. Clearly, the VM is capable of doing this in both version 8 and version 9, which is not surprising since I don't believe that any changes were made to the VM in version 9. Thus, although this problem resembles the one discussed in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25075) question, I don't think the bugs are actually related.

However, the `` CCodeGenerator` `` package *was* changed in version 9, and appears to have become broken in this respect. **In conclusion: it's a bug--please report it.**

Since bugs may not be fixed in a publicly available release for some time, you can work around the issue simply by removing the reference to `Print` and returning the value of `i` instead:

```
Clear[cf1];
cf1 = Compile[{},
   Module[{s = 0.0},
    Do[If[s > 15, Return[i]]; s = s + 1.0/i, {i, 10^7}]
   ], CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ];

cf1[]
```