# Possible Compile bug

Tags: bugs, compile

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier**

The program:

```
 CoprimeTriplets = 
  Compile[{n}, 
   Module[{c = 0}, 
    Do[If[CoprimeQ[i, j, i - j], ++c], {i, 3, n}, {j, 1, IntegerPart[i/2]}];
  c], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];CoprimeTriplets[1000]
```

with c=0 gives wrong answer, whereas with c=1:

```
 CoprimeTriplets = 
  Compile[{n}, 
   Module[{c = 1}, 
    Do[If[CoprimeQ[i, j, i - j], ++c], {i, 3, n}, {j, 1, IntegerPart[i/2]}]; 
  c-1], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]; CoprimeTriplets[1000]
```

gives correct answer c-1 = 152095

Check:

```
c = 0; n = 1000;  
  Do[ If[CoprimeQ[i, j, i - j], ++c], {i, 3, n}, {j, 1,IntegerPart[i/2]}]; c
```

This happens for all n in the compiled version...

Mathematica 11.3

In the above example, we are checking number of all possible solutions to r+s=t up to t=n, such that {r,s,t} are coprime.

Comment: Perhaps you should be made aware that [`CoprimeQ[]` is **not** a compilable function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101).

Comment: Yes, but how it compiles with c=1?

Comment: Seems to be the same bug as mentioned here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25075/1871

Comment: @xzczd Not the same (different broken/fixed/broken dates). I reported this new one.

Comment: Until it is fixed, a workaround may be to use `Block` instead of `Module`.